# What is the default_type_params feature used for in Rust?

Tags: rust

I see some Rust code that looks like this:

```
#![feature(default_type_params)]
```

After a lot of Googling, I get nothing about it. What is this? When should I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enabling feature called default type parameters, but you already know that, so let me show you an example:

```
#![feature(default_type_params)]

struct Foo<A=(int, char)> { // default type parameter here!
    a: A
}

fn default_foo(x: Foo) {
   let (_i, _c): (int, char) = x.a;
}

fn main() {
   default_foo(Foo { a: (1, 'a') })
}
```

Without default type parameters, you would need to explicitly set parameters:

```
struct Foo<A> {
    a: A
}

fn default_foo(x: Foo<(int, char>)) {
   let (_i, _c): (int, char) = x.a;
}

fn main() {
   default_foo(Foo { a: (1, 'a') })
}
```

Example stolen from here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/11217